# Error: Expected a Statement / C++ / Visual Studio

Tags: c++

As I plan to make a small game to test myself on what I know so far in C++, I found that using this is giving me an error at the location of the "else".
Can anyone help?

```
int lvlup()
{
    if (user.xp >= user.maxxp)
        user.xp = 0;
        user.maxxp + 10;
        user.maxhealth += user.maxhealth * .5;
        user.defense + 2;
        user.attack + 3;
        user.lvl + 1;
    else
        return 0;
};
```

Comment: Is this function a method of a class? What is `user`? Also if you get into the `if` statement there is no `return` statement. Also you have a bunch of statements that use `+` instead of (what I assume should be `+=`, so they effectively do nothing

Comment: `{{{{}}}}}` pick some up from here!

Answer (score 1):

You need to group statements with `{}` in c++, and you don't need a `;` after the function.

You also have missed the = sign in a few places. I'm assuming user is a global, but it really should be passed in, but I'll leave that up to you.

I'm assuming the return value is whether the user leveled up, so that really should be a `bool`, not an `int`. I've added a return statement to the `if` true block. Depending on the use of lvlup that may or may not make sense. If the return value is not used you shouldn't have any and use `void`.

So your code should be:

```
int lvlup()
{
    if (user.xp >= user.maxxp)
    {
        user.xp = 0;
        user.maxxp += 10;
        user.maxhealth += user.maxhealth * .5;
        user.defense += 2;
        user.attack += 3;
        user.lvl += 1;

        return 1;
    }
    else
        return 0;
}
```

If your `if/else` statement has only one line you can choose not to have any braces, but if there is more than one line to be executed in response to the conditional you need to include them. However not including them can open up the possibility for someone maintaining the code to make a mistake and not put them in when adding a line to the block, so some people say always add them.

Comment: True @CoryKramer, but that's the answer to the main question.

Comment: @CoryKramer, added the return, but I've already addressed the `user`. I'm assuming it is a global, which is yucky, but legal.

Answer (score 0):

You need some brackets {}.
In fact, the if brunch and the for loop only execute the next line if no brackets found surrounding the piece of code.
example :

```
a = 1;
if (a == 0)
    std::cout << "This line is skipped" << endl;
    std::cout << "This line will appear" << endl;
```

If you execute this code, the output will be:

```
This line will appear
```

and if an else is following the if statement, a compilation error is generated which is your case :p

and if you write down some brackets to structure your code like below:

```
a = 0;
if (a == 0) {
    std::cout << "This line is not skipped" << endl;
    std::cout << "This line will appear too" << endl;
}
```

the output will be :

```
This line is not skipped
This line will appear too
```

The for loop will only loop the only line next to the for loop if no brackets found too.